# I have 5 sticks of dynamite and upon pushing the plunger, each has a % chance of detonating.

Tags: probability

Dynamite stick 1 has a 52% chance of Detonating.

Dynamite stick 2 has a 50% chance of Detonating.

Dynamite stick 3 has a 50% chance of Detonating.

Dynamite stick 4 has a 50% chance of Detonating.

Dynamite stick 5 has a 50% chance of Detonating.

When pushing the plunger I wish to know how to calculate the chance of no sticks detonating, 1 stick detonating, of 2 sticks detonating and of 3 sticks detonating?
The maximum number of sticks that can detonate with one push is 3.

I also wish to know how to calculate the % chance of each stick detonating 1st, 2nd or 3rd under these conditions using these % if only 1 stick can detonate at a time.

Comment: I'll try to put this across a bit better using the context that it is actually applying to, I just thought that using dynamite as an example would make it easier to understand.

This all relates to a game I am playing.
I like to look into thing in more depth and discover how things work.

Comment: In said game you have 5 cards that each have an ability they can use.
The chances of each card using it's ability have been calculated already.
In one turn a maximum of 3 abilities can activate.
Using the above % chances with each stick being a different card. I wanted to work out the chances of 0,1,2 and 3 of these abilities going off and also the chances of each cards ability being the 1st 2nd and 3rd card to fire if 3 did fire?

Comment: I am not actually looking for the answer, as that would be a cop out. I'm more looking for an explanation on how I can go about figuring this out for myself with the information I have.

Comment: Using the same deck of 5 with exactly the same chance on each card, u get many different outcomes, for example only card 1 fires, card 1 and 4 fire in the order 1 and then 4, only 1 and 4 fire in the order 4 and then 1.
Each card can fire with a maximum of 3 firing in one given turn.

Comment: There is actually an extra modifier added to card number one, hence my explanation having the extra 2% added to Dynamite stick 1. I assumed this wouldn't make any difference to the calculations used though as it can be calculated by simply upping card ones % by 2%.

Answer (score 1):

To get no sticks, you multiply the chance that each one doesn't detonate.  To get one stick, you sum over the sticks.  The chance that only stick 1 fires is the chance that it fires times the chance that all the rest don't.  You have to add these up over the five choices of which stick fires.

This sort of calculation will report a chance that all five detonate.  It is not clear how to impose your restriction that no more than 3 will detonate at one try-is there some sort of priority order, so if 1,2, and 3 all detonate then 4 and 5 are not tried?

Similarly in your last question, on each try do you select a stick that might fire?  You have not made the process clear.

Comment: The restriction is that when you push the plunger which is a 1 time thing, a restriction of only 3 being able to fire on that 1 push has been added.
The % chance set to each stick firing is also the % chance of it firing at all.
There is no priority, only that you are given the % chance of the stick firing and told that only a maximum of 3 can fire on a push.

Comment: @Damo:  then the chances that they fire are not independent and we need to know how they interact.  Alternately, you can just pretend that 4 or 5 fire and group all the chances of 3,4,5 into the chance that 3 fire.  Maybe that is what is intended.